# How to turn an entire website into a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, web

My law practice involves a government agency that has decided to turn a 400+ page manual into a website. I need to periodically turn the website into a manual so that I can see what rules governed at a particular time. Is there a way to automatically turn the website into a pdf file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/371670/12705907 this might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best solution for turning a website into a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371670/best-solution-for-turning-a-website-into-a-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called wkhtmltopdf that can help you. But you need to scrape yourself, probably in a way that is specific to the site you want to convert.